# nano - soft wrap at 80 characters

Tags: editors, newlines, nano

I would like `nano` to soft-wrap at 80 characters. That is, as I keep typing, the text should flow to the next line beyond 80 characters, without `nano` insert a `\n` newline at 80 characters.

```
set softwrap
set tabsize 4
set tabstospaces
set fill 72
```

However, this inserts a newline after each line, when tested with cat.

How do I softwrap and fill simultaneously?

Comment: Look at the "comment #3" here:
https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=51620

Answer (score 0):

Your 'set fill' command asks for hard wrapping at column 72 (I think). Have you actually tried this up to column 80?

You need to lose the 'set fill' command, really.

Comment: If I get rid of `set fill`, my lines will go from the left extreme of my screen to the right extreme, which I don't want. Is there a way to force both options?